# Laravel Datatable skipTotalRecords() not working. Still fetching count row

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

I'm using Laravel and Laravel DataTable ^8.0 version. Adding Dataable skipTotalRecords() in DataTable eloquent builder not working. Count query still coming in results. Here is attaching my screenshots

**From clockwork debug bar**

SELECT count(*) as aggregate FROM (SELECT `id`, `row_no`, `customer_id`, `income`, `posting_date`, (SELECT `posting_date` FROM `final_invoice` WHERE `job_id` = `job`.`id` and `final_invoice`.`deleted_at` IS NULL and `final_invoice`.`company_id` = '1' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1) as `invoice_date`, (SELECT SUM(local_amount) as income FROM `finance` WHERE `account` = '7035500' and `job_no` = `job`.`row_no` and `finance`.`deleted_at` IS NULL and `finance`.`company_id` = '1' LIMIT 1) as `posted_income` FROM `job` WHERE `income` > '0' and `posting_date` between '2021-03-01' and '2021-03-29' and `job`.`deleted_at` IS NULL and `job`.`company_id` = '1') count_row_table

SELECT `id`, `row_no`, `customer_id`, `income`, `posting_date`, (SELECT `posting_date` FROM `final_invoice` WHERE `job_id` = `job`.`id` and `final_invoice`.`deleted_at` IS NULL and `final_invoice`.`company_id` = '1' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1) as `invoice_date`, (SELECT SUM(local_amount) as income FROM `finance` WHERE `account` = '7035500' and `job_no` = `job`.`row_no` and `finance`.`deleted_at` IS NULL and `finance`.`company_id` = '1' LIMIT 1) as `posted_income` FROM `job` WHERE `income` > '0' and `posting_date` between '2021-03-01' and '2021-03-29' and `job`.`deleted_at` IS NULL and `job`.`company_id` = '1' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 25 offset 0

**Code**

```
->skipTotalRecords()
->toJson();
```

**Composer JSON**

```
"itsgoingd/clockwork": "^4.0",
"laravel/cashier": "^12.1",
"laravel/framework": "^8.0",
"yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.0",
```

Please help me out why count query still running. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Too many nested queries. You must understand that for each record on the outermost table, the inner query executes. Given that you are SELECTing values from a query for each row in outer query, performance becomes worse if the tables are huge.
I would suggest you to use JOINs instead.